# connecting external mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

Is that possible to connect mysql database between servers. I mean, lets say i have 2 accounts on 2 different hosting service, one of them has database, and i want to connect it from other one with php.

When i try it, i get "Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server during query..."

my database is located on godaddy and i set it external access enabled.

Edit:
I see it is possible but my host only allows connection via software;

"To use Direct Database Access to connect remotely to your shared hosting database, you need to download software that lets you connect to the database and manage it."

Comment: Should "work" but aside from some possible intermittent connection issues like you seem to describe, you should typically expect a significant loss of performance when accessing a remote server on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very possible.

Make sure the host that has your database allows for external connections and allows that username/password combination to access the database (Usually something set via mySQL's GRANT option)