# Connecting to the Client Database from Server

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [connecting external mysql database with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698655/connecting-external-mysql-database-with-php)

I have desingned a form. The Data entered in the form, gets saved on my local machine database as well as on server database *when i execute it on my localmachine using wamp*. The same file i uploaded it on server, when i enter the data, the data gets saved only on my server database. Data is not getting saved on my local database. Is there any method to connect to local machine database from server.
Language i used for coding is php/mysql.

Comment: is this the best idea? will your local machine always be on? why do you need the data in two databases?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method to connect to local machine database from server

Yes there is. You just configure the local database to accept connections from the remote host your script is running on and give your script the WAN hostname and port of your database server.

This is nothing that special, sort of standard database configuration. The database vendor will offer you more dedicated support in your individual issue for your specific configuration, you might want to try as well the Mysql support forums and mailinglist.

Comment: @Rafee: Well, OP should know what he does I think he is old enough, but obviously the question has been asked before, I'll kill my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can ... only need is: you need a dns or ip for the server-connection (you can simple use dyndns to get one for free) and you need to open the port 3306 on your "modem" or what ever and forward-it to your wamp-server ....